# Can we get statistics on tag popularity?

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, tags

Can we get nice-looking statistics on tag popularity, like [this](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/#!c%23+java+android+jquery)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely!

Just a little URL magic gives us:
http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/mi_yodeya/tags/#!halacha+minhag+food

Comment: I hereby renounce my "programmer" tag. :-)

Comment: Isaac's answer will actually give you more up to date information though.

Comment: While that may be, your answer is the most precise when considering my usage of "nice-looking" and "like this". I didn't say "up to date".

Answer (score 5):

You can run [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/miyodeya/query/94158/tag-popularity-comparison#graph) with a list of tags that you choose, e.g. `'shabbat', 'minhag', 'history', 'tefilla', 'parshanut-torah-comment'` (the top five that aren't [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha), which dwarfs everything).